# How do I make a whole li element clickable to toggle checkmark? (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: jquery, list, checkbox, bootstrap-4

I have a list where each line has name on the left and a checkmark on the right, I want to be able to just click on the whole element to toggle the checkbox, be it with javascript or html.

```
  <li href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <span><img class="menu-icon" src="icon.png">Menu 1</span>
    <label class="checkbox my-auto">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an event listener on the li tag to toggle checkbox on click like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.list-group-item').on('click', function() {
        let checkbox = $(this).find('input');            
        if (li.prop('checked') == true) 
            li.prop('checked', false);
        else 
            li.prop('checked', true);
    });
}
```